# AVAudioPlayer and Simulator cause bluetooth headphone audio to seize

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios-simulator, avfoundation

I'm not sure if this question belongs on Ask Different or SO. It's a bit of both.

I recently went wireless with my headphones that I use for work. I have Bose QC35s hooked up to my MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra over bluetooth. I'm having an odd problem when running the iOS Simulator while listening to music in iTunes. When my app launches, it plays a sound effect using AVAudioPlayer. The act of playing the sound causes iTunes to stall and beginning playing an indefinite 0.5 second loop of the current track. I have to restart iTunes to continue listening. You can imagine how annoying that would get doing a regular workday.

The code that causes it is simple:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

var player : AVAudioPlayer! = nil

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "intro", withExtension: "m4a")
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: url!)
        }
        catch {
            return
        }

        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.delegate = self
        player.play() // This line causes the audio issue
    }
}
```

Restarting iTunes gets things working again. And from there on out, I'm free to play more sound effects in the app. The problem only happens on the first sound played after the app is launched.

Does anyone know how to prevent this problem from happening?

### Some other info about the issue:

- It happens in Objective-C as well
- It's a problem in both iPhone and iPad simulators
- It also happens with Beats Studio Wireless, and I assume all other bluetooth headphones.
- Running the app on a device does not trigger the problem
- If I pause iTunes while the first sound effect in the Simulator plays, I can resume listening without issue

Comment: File a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com and include a sysdiagnose.  Make sure you are in this state with your BT audio device attached.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia thanks for the comment. filed. 29510053.

Comment: Thanks, sent it along to the right folks.  Feel free to ping me out-of-band if you have any questions about it, and I'll do what I can.  I know radar can seem like a black hole to developers on the outside, but trust me, it's not, and reports are very appreciated.

Comment: Will do. I appreciate the followup!